# Is a perfectly-absorbing sphere ill-defined?

Tags: waves, absorption, multipole-expansion

Suppose we have a spherical object that absorbs without reflection scalar waves (e.g. sound waves) incident on it. We should expect that the incident wave will get a shadow in the corresponding region behind the sphere, which will gradually wash out due to diffraction.

To model it, we can try to go as follows. A plane wave propagating along $\hat z$ axis can be expanded in spherical waves as<sup>[1]</sup>

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{plane}(r,\theta)=\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty i^\ell(2\ell+1) j_\ell(kr) P_\ell(\cos\theta),
\end{equation}

where $k$ is the wavenumber, $j_\ell$ are the [spherical Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_Bessel_functions#Spherical_Bessel_functions:_jn,_yn) of the first kind, and $P_\ell$ are the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).

Since we want the wave to be completely absorbed, it seems natural to replace $j_\ell$ with the spherical Hankel function of the second kind $h^{(2)}_\ell$, which represents a converging wave—effectively removing the expanding part $h^{(1)}_\ell(kr)$ from the spherical Bessel function.

But then we have a problem: not only are spherical Hankel functions unbounded at the origin, but the expansion coefficients are proportional to $2\ell+1$, which makes the growth increase with multipole moment. Add to this that the unbounded growth starts further out as $\ell$ increases, and the resulting series diverges everywhere.

So, is the concept of a perfectly-absorbing sphere ill-defined? Or is there a mistake in my reasoning above?

---

##### References

1. William J. Thompson, [*"A concise derivation of the plane‐wave partial‐wave expansion"*](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.16881). American Journal of Physics 60, 378 (1992).

Comment: I'm probably not following your argument here, but why can't you use the same argument to say that the plane wave expansion in terms of $j_\ell$ is divergent as well?  (Of course, the plane wave *isn't* divergent — so if you can't find a difference between the argument for $h^{(1)}_\ell$ and the argument for $j_\ell$ then there must be an error in the logic somewhere.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert spherical Hankel functions $h_\ell^{(1)}$ have order-$(\ell+1)$ poles at $r=0$, which spherical Bessel functions of the first kind $j_\ell$ don't have. In fact, $j_\ell$ behave similar to monomials of order $\ell$ at the origin, letting the series converge similarly to Taylor series.

Comment: Right, but why does that matter?  $r = 0$ isn't part of the space we're considering.  And if we're not at a singular point (i.e., $r \neq 0$) it's perfectly permissible to think about a power series around that singular point that includes inverse powers of the variable, *cf.* [Laurent series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert functions with poles have an annoying tendency to grow rapidly when approaching a pole. The higher the order of the pole, the faster the growth. In particular, when $\ell\sim ka$, the fast-growing part of the spherical Hankel reaches the radius $a$, and further increase of $\ell$ extends this enormity further. Each new term adds to the growth, and the further you sum the series, the wilder the results you get at greater radii (with all the smaller radii of course getting even wilder). Of course, there's no hope to have a finite limit of the sum, thus the series diverges.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert the point about Laurent series is interesting. But, experimentally, the expansion in spherical Hankel functions does become wilder with increasing maximum $\ell$, so I suppose it diverges. Will have to check Laurent series convergence criteria...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**: The problem is not ill-posed.

**Longer Answer**:

There are a couple of mistakes in your reasoning.  First, if you only have converging waves, then you can't have the diffraction on the far side of the sphere, or the normal propagation in the $\hat z$ direction far from the sphere.  Second, your absorption requirement is at the surface of the sphere, at $r=a$, where $a$ is the radius of the sphere.  Thus, the fact that a solution has diverging terms at $r=0$ does not make the problem ill-posed; it just does not include that point.

I believe the best way to look at the problem is to decompose the total field into an incident plane wave plus a scattered wave.  The incident plane wave is just as you have described it, while the scattered wave (which consists entirely of out-propagating fields) would be written as
$$\text{scattered}(r,\theta)=A_lh_l^{(1)}(kr)P_l(\cos\theta),$$
where $A_l$ are constants that need to be determined by the boundary condition.  Next, you need to mathematically describe what you mean by "perfectly absorbing".  Generally, this will be a requirement of the form
$$u(a,\theta)+B\hat r\cdot\nabla u(a,\theta)=C,$$
where $u$ is the field in question [i.e., $u(r,\theta)=\text{plane}(r,\theta)+\text{scattered}(r,\theta)$], and $B$ and $C$ are some constants.  The boundary condition might be more complicated, depending on how many physical phenomena you are trying to capture.  Inserting the series expansion of $u(r,\theta)$ into the boundary condition and appealing to the orthogonality of the Legendre polynomials then gives an infinite number of independent equations for $A_l$ in terms of the plane wave, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: _"Thus, the fact that a solution has diverging terms at $r=0$
 does not make the problem ill-posed; it just does not include that point."_ — I didn't imply the singularity at a point is the problem. The actual problem is that the function becomes enormous at radius proportional to $\ell$ (and smaller), which, after we sum the series, renders the whole series divergent at _every_ point. We sum over $\ell$ with ever-increasing coefficients.

Comment: @Ruslan:  I think this approach might solve the problem you outlined in our discussion above.  If the $h_\ell^{(1)}$ functions get very large at $r = a$ above a certain value of $\ell$, then (since they're required to cancel out with the incident wave via the boundary condition) the corresponding $A_\ell$ coefficients have to get very small.  This could kill off the series divergence at high $\ell$.  (Maybe?)

Comment: _"First, if you only have converging waves, then you can't have the diffraction on the far side of the sphere"_ — in fact, I think this made me realize my mistake. Indeed, if I only have converging waves, I'll have nothing detected in the far field, not even the unshaded part of the incident wave, let alone the diffracted part.